# Binning in healpy maps?

Tags: python, astronomy, healpy

I have a healpy map where each pixel value is some meaningful physical measurement. I would like to bin the map into "squares" with side length, say, 5 degrees. Basically I want to average pixel values in each 5 deg^2 bin. Is there any straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want to keep the data in the HEALPix format? In that case, [hp.ud_grade()](https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/healpy.pixelfunc.ud_grade.html) will do exactly what you need. The caveat is that you can't choose arbitrary squares, but need to stick to the (quadratic and rotated) HEALPix pixels.

Comment: Yes this is true, expect I should have been more specific. I also want to take the variance of all points within each bin. So using hp.ud_grade() will only help me with the average, not the variance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that healpy supports both the ring and the nested ordering to achieve that. For every resolution step, four high resolution pixels make up one low resolution pixel.

```py
  import healpy as hp
  import numpy as np

  nside_high = 2
  npix_high = hp.nside2npix(nside_high)
  arr = np.arange(npix_high)

  hp.mollview(arr)
```

[image]

Now, using the nested ordering, we can compute the mean in each low resolution pixel. This is equivalent to using `hp.ud_grade(arr, nside_low)`.

```py
  nside_low = 1
  order_diff = nside_high - nside_low

  arr_lowres = hp.reorder(arr, r2n=True).reshape((-1, 4**order_diff)).mean(axis=1)
  hp.mollview(arr_lowres, nest=True)
```

[image]

Lastly, we can substitute `mean` with `std` to get the standard deviation:

```py
  arr_std = hp.reorder(arr, r2n=True).reshape((-1, 4**order_diff)).std(axis=1)
  hp.mollview(arr_std, nest=True)
```

[image]

Comment: This is clever, but ideally I'd like to have a list of pixels in the high res map for each bin. While your method allows me to compute the standard dev and avg of bins, I also not to loop through pixels within each bin. I don't think this method allows me to do that. Any ideas how I can get a list of pixels in the high res map for each bin?

Comment: Sure, that's exactly what `hp.reorder(arr, r2n=True).reshape((-1, 4**order_diff))` does in the above code :) It'll give you a 2d numpy array, with `shape=(n_large_pixels, n_small_pixels_per_large_pixel)`